# sudo yarn application -kill <app_Id> thinks I am user hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

When the SparkR Backend handler freezes, I have no recourse other than to kill the yarn application... which is its own stackoverflow question... but today, for the first time I'm now getting an error when I try to `sudo` and kill the application:

```
[me@myserver ~]$ sudo yarn application -kill application_1536084816396_0023
18/09/10 15:27:37 INFO client.AHSProxy: Connecting to Application History 
     server at myserver.com/10.20.60.132:10200
18/09/10 15:27:37 INFO client.RequestHedgingRMFailoverProxyProvider: Looking 
     for the active RM in [rm1, rm2]...
18/09/10 15:27:37 INFO client.RequestHedgingRMFailoverProxyProvider: Found 
     active RM [rm2]
Killing application application_1536084816396_0023
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException: 
     java.security.AccessControlException: User hdfs cannot perform 
     operation MODIFY_APP on application_1536084816396_0023
```

Why is `sudo` interpreting me as the `hdfs` user? My `yarn.admin.acl` is set to `dr.who,activity_analyzer,yarn`... which used to do the trick and it doesn't look like it's been changed.

Comment: Why do you need `sudo`? If anything, you need to become the `yarn` user first such as `su yarn -c "yarn application kill ..."`

Comment: Good question. It's how I've been killing jobs for my team when their zeppelin instance fails or there's some other failure of a backend handler (for SparkR). It seems that root is generating a kerberos ticket as hdfs... which is weird. Not sure how that is happening.

Comment: Well, that's probably the root of the issue :) But I don't know Kerberos, so not sure